# three.js sizeAttenuation to Sprite material

Tags: three.js, sprite

I want the sprite in the scene don't change the size when the camera zoom in or out. and the sprites use different canvas texture as the material.

I found that the sizeAttenuation in ParticleBasicMatierial can work for me. But if I use the WenGLRenderer, I must use ParticleSystem instead of the Particle with the CanvasRenderer.

I currently use ParticleSystem to contain only one vertex, and every vertex correspond to one ParticleSystem, so there are about 800+ ParticleSystem in my scene, this can work, but consume a lot.

Obviously, I can't use "HUD" as the example in three.js source, because the sprites are all in 3D scene.

Can some one help me. Or add the sizeAttenuation to Sprite Material! Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to prevent size attenuation with sprites, and you are using a perspective camera, you can set the `sizeAttenuation` property of your material to false:

```
var material = new THREE.SpriteMaterial( {

    color: 0xffffff,
    map: texture,
    sizeAttenuation: false

} );
```

This feature was added in three.js r.96.

EDIT: Updated to three.js r.96

Comment: Hello， WestLangeley， I tried this approach, i does't work well. if I set the scale_factor to 3, the sprite is too big, and I set to 30, look well, but the size attenuation is as before.

Comment: Start with this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9GudA/ and edit it to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: Sorry for my later reply， I had tried a few times more, it did work well, thanks very much for your help!